# Sufficient condition for the existence of a joint probability distribution over a set of variables?

Tags: probability-theory

Is the following claim true?

If each random variable in a set V is measurable with respect to some probability space (W,S,P), then P assigns a probability to each possible combination of values of the variables in V.

It (or something like it with better wording) seems obviously true, but I can't find a straightforward reference to it. Any help would be appreciated.